# I would like to delete a row from a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, sql-delete

The first part of the program, which reads the database works fine, the problem is with deleting. The database looks like: ID, Username and Text.

The code I'm currently using:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
    Dim strQuery As String = ""
    Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    Private Sub Delete()
        Try
            dbCon = New     MySqlConnection(Connection string)
            strQuery = "Delete * FROM otletek WHERE id = " & TextBox2.Text
            SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
            dbCon.Open()
            MsgBox(strQuery)
            dbCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Connection error" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: DELETE * is not mysql syntax

Comment: You may want to Execute that non-query.

Comment: `DELETE FROM otletek WHERE id = " & TextBox2.Text` would be the proper syntax. You can reference the `DELETE` statement in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the code that executes the SQL command?

SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
strQuery = "Delete FROM otletek WHERE id = " & TextBox2.Text
```

it's a SQL injection waiting to happen - bad idea.